# Databricks init script to install Datadog not working

Tags: databricks, datadog

I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2017/06/01/apache-spark-cluster-monitoring-with-databricks-and-datadog.html) to install and configure the Datadog agent in a cluster-scoped init script. The script doesn't actually start the child script it creates to actually install and configure Datadog.

Here's the script generated by the notebook imported from the above blog post:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "Running on the driver? $DB_IS_DRIVER"
echo "Driver ip: $DB_DRIVER_IP"

cat <<EOF >> /tmp/start_datadog.sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ \$DB_IS_DRIVER = "TRUE" ]; then
  echo "On the driver. Installing Datadog ..."
  
  # install the Datadog agent
  DD_API_KEY=<MY_API_KEY> bash -c "\$(curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataDog/datadog-agent/master/cmd/agent/install_script.sh)"
  
  # WAITING UNTIL MASTER PARAMS ARE LOADED, THEN GRABBING IP AND PORT
  while [ -z \$gotparams ]; do
    if [ -e "/tmp/driver-env.sh" ]; then
      DB_DRIVER_PORT=\$(grep -i "CONF_UI_PORT" /tmp/driver-env.sh | cut -d'=' -f2)
      gotparams=TRUE
    fi
    sleep 2
  done

  current=\$(hostname -I | xargs)  
  
  # WRITING SPARK CONFIG FILE FOR STREAMING SPARK METRICS
  echo "init_config:
instances:
    - resourcemanager_uri: http://\$DB_DRIVER_IP:\$DB_DRIVER_PORT
      spark_cluster_mode: spark_driver_mode
      cluster_name: \$current" > /etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/spark.yaml

  # RESTARTING AGENT
  sudo service datadog-agent restart

fi
EOF

# CLEANING UP
if [ \$DB_IS_DRIVER = "TRUE" ]; then
  chmod a+x /tmp/start_datadog.sh
  /tmp/start_datadog.sh >> /tmp/datadog_start.log 2>&1 & disown
fi
```

The event log for the cluster in the Databricks console says it finished running the init scripts but I launch `Web Terminal` in the Databricks console and I see the child script is not running at all:

```sh
root@1122-180908-gh1ahrr7-10-4-32-233:/databricks/driver# sh -x /dbfs/init-scripts/datadog-install-driver-only-v2.sh
+ echo Running on the driver? 
Running on the driver? 
+ echo Driver ip: 
Driver ip: 
+ cat
+ [ $DB_IS_DRIVER = TRUE ]
root@1122-180908-gh1ahrr7-10-4-32-233:/databricks/driver# 

root@1122-180908-gh1ahrr7-10-4-39-90:/databricks/driver# ifconfig 
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9001
      inet 10.4.39.90  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 10.4.255.255
...

root@1122-180908-gh1ahrr7-10-4-39-90:/databricks/driver# cat /dbfs/cluster-logs/1122-180908-gh1ahrr7/init_scripts/1122-180908-gh1ahrr7_10_4_39_90/20230109_212735_00_datadog-install-driver-only-v2.sh.stdout.log
Running on the driver? TRUE
Driver ip: 10.4.39.90
root@1122-180908-gh1ahrr7-10-4-39-90:/databricks/driver#
```

I'm also looking at the Advanced cluster config in the Databricks console and and see the `Driver hostname` mentioned under the SSH config is different: `10.4.58.10`.

Why is the SSH IP different from the IP the Web Terminal logs me into? Is this the reason for the cluster init script not working? And what is the solution?

Comment: what's inside `/tmp/datadog_start.log`? add `set -x` and `set +x` at top/bottom of the script. Are you sure the init script ran (Event Log in cluster config)? what do the cluster logs say (stdout/err)?

Comment: @Kashyap `/tmp/datadog_start.log` doesn't exist. The script never gets past the
`if [ \$DB_IS_DRIVER = "TRUE" ]; then` step.
I've updated the question to include the output with `set -x`:


```
root@1122-180908-gh1ahrr7-10-4-32-233:/databricks/driver# sh -x /dbfs/init-scripts/datadog-install-driver-only-v2.sh
+ echo Running on the driver? 
Running on the driver? 
+ echo Driver ip: 
Driver ip: 
+ cat
+ [ $DB_IS_DRIVER = TRUE ]
root@1122-180908-gh1ahrr7-10-4-32-233:/databricks/driver# 
```

Comment: also, @Kashyap the event log says it finished init scripts execution.

Comment: seems pretty black and white that variables `DB_IS_DRIVER` and `DB_DRIVER_IP` are not set causing the init script to fail. I guess if you look at stderr you'll find a syntax error at `if [ \$DB_IS_DRIVER = "TRUE" ]`. I am surprised that `/tmp/datadog_start.log` doesn't exist. Most likely you're looking at the wrong machine.

Comment: @Kashyap I missed pasting the correct invocation but even if I run it like this it still fails:
```
# ifconfig 
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9001
        inet 10.4.32.233  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 10.4.255.255
# export DB_IS_DRIVER="TRUE"
# export DB_DRIVER_IP=10.4.32.233
# sh -x /dbfs/init-scripts/datadog-install-driver-only-v2.sh
+ echo Running on the driver? TRUE
Running on the driver? TRUE
+ echo Driver ip: 10.4.32.233
Driver ip: 10.4.32.233
+ cat
+ [ $DB_IS_DRIVER = TRUE ]
root@1122-180908-gh1ahrr7-10-4-32-233:/databricks/driver#
```

Comment: @Kashyap why would I land on the wrong machine if I'm using the web terminal to login to the cluster? Shouldn't it land me on the driver node?

Comment: could you add the output to OP. Can't really make out much in this comment section. wrong machine: Because I (incorrectly) thought there is no way the line that invokes the script would fail to create the log file. But it'd not even execute due to the if condition it's wrapped inside. dbk guys have written a pretty poor shell script, from debugging pov.

Comment: 1. replace `if [ \$DB_IS_DRIVER = "TRUE" ]` with `if [ "X\$DB_IS_DRIVER" = "XTRUE" ]` (same at bottom too). 2. Add `else` to every `if` in the script and add some `echo "inside else, unexpected..."` in the else. Re-run and debug.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251049/discussion-between-hyperwiser-and-kashyap).

Answer (score 1):

you can add this to just before the check condition and it should work.

```
cat <<EOF > /tmp/start_datadog.sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f /databricks/driver/conf/spark-branch.conf ]; then
    export DB_IS_DRIVER=TRUE
    echo $DB_IS_DRIVER
fi

if [[ \${DB_IS_DRIVER} = "TRUE" ]]; then
  
  echo "Installing Datadog Agent on the driver..."
```

How ever I ran into other issues where I had to manually set cluster name and now spark url is also not getting formed correctly. Looking on troubleshooting that.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly OT perhaps, but there it is - please have the sum total of wisdom gleaned for 2 months of attacking this stuff.

Take a look at this script:

https://gist.github.com/abij/95b47edf8b6d176fba9ec796da96b715

This kind person has coalesced the standalone and single node cluster logic into one script, which should help with driver vs. driver+worker case.

For those having hostname issues with the agent from version 7.40.x, you can add this to your Spark env config (don't add quotes; the agent install script won't strip them out when building the download url):

```
DD_AGENT_MINOR_VERSION=39.0
```

The [Datadog integration page](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/databricks/?tab=driveronly) seems to also have been recently updated to address this hostname issue:

```
# CONFIGURE HOSTNAME EXPLICITLY IN datadog.yaml TO PREVENT AGENT FROM FAILING ON VERSION 7.40+
  # SEE https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-agent/issues/14152 FOR CHANGE
  hostname=\$(hostname | xargs)
  echo "hostname: \$hostname" >> /etc/datadog-agent/datadog.yaml
```

Also, be prepared to have to change the `process_config` `expvar_port` from the default of `6062` to something like `6163`, as the Spark java procs will attempt to `bind()` to ports in the `606x` range, which means the Spark driver won't even come up.

The `datadog-agent` config offers the `DD_PROCESS_CONFIG_EXPVAR_PORT` as a way to override this (without having to `sed` the config from the init script), *but* - from spelunking through the `datadog-agent`, it appears the envvar is not bound/considered by the agent, and is therefore inert.. There is an [Issue in for this](https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-agent/issues/15191).

Save yourself headaches and use the other way around this via the [Spark config](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/ipywidgets.html):

```
By default, ipywidgets occupies port 6062. With Databricks Runtime 11.2 and above, if you run into conflicts with third-party integrations such as Datadog, you can change the port using the following Spark config:

spark.databricks.driver.ipykernel.commChannelPort <port-number>

For example:

spark.databricks.driver.ipykernel.commChannelPort 1234

The Spark config must be set when the cluster is created.
```

Hoping this can save some time and energy for others.